# replace empty datasets

Tags: python

Sorry, I agree that was really poorly written:

Take 2:
I have many columns of data (up to 63) in over 50 datasets.  I am extracting only 3 columns of data that I need and writing it into a new .csv file.  There are a few of my datasets that do not have the third desired column of data.  But that's okay I can leave it blank (or insert another value like "-" or whatever).  I don't want to open all my files to figure out which files have what.  The error message I get when I try to extract data from a non-existent column is:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there a loop that I can write to fix this?
I'm really new to python, and in my head it seems easy but when I try to actually do it it's very difficult.

Thanks

Comment: You're doing **what same thing**? Why would you try to extract data from non-existent columns? If I were you, I'd just not do that...

(In other words, your question is very badly written and pretty much incomprehensible. Please re-write.)

Comment: Kudos for providing the error, but without sample data it's a bit hard to figure out what you're doing

Comment: What thing? What kind of dataset? What column? What code? What output file? Wait... ">>> from pychic import read_mind" "ImportError: No module named pychic". Sorry.

Comment: I updated my question...sorry about that

Comment: No, you've changed the question but you haven't provided any useful information. How are you reading the datasets? What *Python code*? What are they stored in -- datatype, variable? You can answer all these questions easily by providing __sample code__.

Comment: For instance, if you are reading csv files, you could tell us `import csv; for line in csv.reader( open( <path-to-file> ) ): ...`

Comment: Please remove "Sorry, I agree that was really poorly written:

Take 2:"  It conveys no information at all.  It's useless.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, I'm guessing you have a list of lists that looks something like this (a gross simplification):

```
[[0,1,2,3],
[1,2,3,4,5],
[1,2,3],
[1,2,3]]
```

And you are trying to do the following:

for row in xrange(4):
   for col in xrange(4):
       #something else?
       print data[row][col]

And then you're getting your error because one of the values doesn't have an element at index 3:

```
+------------------------+
| Index: | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+------------------------+
|Value:  | 1 | 2 | 3 |  <----- No value at index 3
+--------------------+
```

Depending on where you're getting your data from originally, there are several different ways to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

If you provide sample I/O you'll get much better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're doing something like:

```
for line in file:
    parts = line.split()
    blah = line[2]
```

And blah doesn't exist for some lines.

You can check the length of lists:

```
if len(parts) > 2:
    blah = line[2]
else:
    blah = "" # or whatever
```

Without any example code it's hard to be more precise, but this is probably a quick and easy fix for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through all your data before you start, you could just catch the Exception and handle it appropriately:

```
try:
    a = list[57]
except IndexError:
    a = '-'
```